# Beginner Index out of range in python

Tags: python

This is a problem I am working on for a class (below is my question and the code I wrote):

The program should accept a series of students and their exam scores in response to a 
"?" prompt. Enter the two digit exam score (no one ever gets 100 or less than 10), a single
space and the name of the student. Keep entering these until the user enters "Stop" – 
your program should be able to handle any form of "Stop" – for example, "stop", "Stop", 
"STOP", "sTOP", etc.
You should then display a list of student names ordered by their exam scores (low to 
high).
For instance (user input is underlined):

```
? 23 Warren
? 44 Dona
? 33 Tom
? stop
Warren
Tom
Dona
```

So I understand everything I've written and I understand that this is not an especially complicated problem. Though, the way my code is written, when I input "stop" to show the program that I am finished with inputs, it runs the input "stop" in the for loop creating a index out of range error. How can I make it run "stop" only in the while loop and not in the for loop?

```
    students = []
    nameScore = ""
    while (nameScore.lower() != "stop"):
        nameScore = input ("? ")
        students.append(nameScore)

    students.sort()

    for student in students:
        x = student.split()
        print (x[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you "break" before you append, then `"stop"` will not be included in `students`.

```
while True:
    nameScore = input ("? ")
    if nameScore.lower() == "stop": break
    students.append(nameScore)
```

Moreover, if you write the `while`-loop this way, you won't need to pre-initialize `nameScore`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the flow of the program just a bit and have it "prime" the input string before entering the while loop; that way it'll check before it appends the input:

```
students = []
nameScore = input("? ")
while nameScore.lower() != "stop":
    students.append(nameScore)
    nameScore = input ("? ")

students.sort()

for student in students:
    x = student.split()
    print (x[1])
```

A bit of code repetition, but it does the job.

Another way to do it is to use a [list slice](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) to remove the last element:

```
students = []
nameScore = ""
while nameScore.lower() != "stop":
    students.append(nameScore)
    nameScore = input ("? ")

students = students[:-1]    # Remove the last element
students.sort()

for student in students:
    x = student.split()
    print (x[1])
```

By the way, the parenthesis around the while condition aren't necessary in Python.